# PyQt disabling Java Script alerts

Tags: python, pyqt

Hi I am creating a browser in python using PyQt, I am trying to allow the user to disable all Java Script alerts which is a protected function under qwebpage called javaScriptAlert, is there a way to disable this function or protected functions in general?

Comment: show your code, There are several modules that are used in PyQt to make a browser.

Comment: Yes, it's very simple. Just subclass either QWebPage (QtWebKit) or QWebEnginePage (QtWebEngine) and override the `javaScriptAlert` method: `class MyWebPage(QWebPage): def javaScriptAlert(self): pass`.

Comment: In my main class I put class MainWindow(QMainWindow, QWebPage): def javaScriptAlert(QWebPage), would that work?

Comment: Do you know a way to incorporate a separate class and define self as QWebPage like the example above if you can incorporate it back into the main window class?

Answer (score 1):

in the main class where browser can be defined as

```
self.browser = QWebView()
```

and then do another class

```
class MyWebPage(QWebPage): 
    def javaScriptAlert(self): 
        pass
```

then back in the main class do

```
self.page = MyWebPage()
self.browser.setPage(self.page)
```